# Java exception breakpoint with condition in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Is there any way (including a third-party plug-in) to make a Java exception breakpoint in Eclipse **that only breaks if a condition is true**?

*Current Use Case*: I am trying to catch a `ClassNotFoundException` for a particular class in order to debug a class loading issue. Unfortunately, my breakpoint is trapping literally thousands of irrelevant routine exceptions that occur on Tomcat startup. I want to tell Eclipse to break only if `-1 < e.getMessage().indexOf(MY_CLASS_NAME)`.

Help!?

**Update**: Several answers have suggested to right-click on the exception in the exception properties and click conditional breakpoint. I've already tried this. Up to at least Eclipse Luna Release 2 (v 4.4.2, build id 20150219-0600), this is not option available for ***exception*** *breakpoints*.

For clarity, here is a picture of my exception breakpoint's properties:

[image]

Comment: How about adding a regular breakpoint on `ClassNotFoundException(String s)` constructor and putting your condition in that breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to add a condition for an exception breakpoint similar to normal breakpoints. The closest thing you can do is use the **Filtering** properties page to add a filter on the breakpoint such as the class and/or the package which throws the exception. Or you can filter on a specific thread while debugging.

See http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-create-exception-filter-expression.htm for more info.

Comment: Filtering could be set to some of the classloader classes that loads tons of classes. How does it help?

Comment: @TMG I guess it could narrow down the search for the class which throws the exception as long as it reduces the number of times execution is suspended.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your break point! -> Properties -> Conditional break point

Comment: I don't have this option for exception breakpoints, only for regular breakpoints. (Note: Eclipse version=Juno Service Release 2, 20130225-0426)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your breakpoint, the last line of the menu: 'Breakpoint properties'. You will find a checkbox with 'Conditional'. Then you only add `-1 < e.getMessage().indexOf(MY_CLASS_NAME)` into the edit box.

Comment: I don't have this option for exception breakpoints, only for regular breakpoints. (Note: Eclipse version=Juno Service Release 2, 20130225-0426)

Comment: You can't add conditions in exceptions breakpoint. The best, is to use a Try .. Catch and put your breakpoint inside, with something like System.out.println(e.getMessage()) and make a conditional breakpoint there.

Comment: I can't edit the code that is throwing. It is in a JAR that is outside my control.

Comment: In the Filtering of the breakpoint, you can select in 'Restrict to Selected Location the package or the class in witch you want to break.